# Using UCMA to connect to 3CX?

Tags: c#, sip, voice, 3cx, ucma2.0

Has anyone used Microsoft's UCMA 2.0 SDK to connect to 3CX's free IP PBX to add voice capabilities to their application?  If so, does it work?  What I am trying to accomplish is having a windows form app running on 2 or more computers, and each person can connect to another person and carry on a voice conversation using their headset connected to their computer.  App is in C# w/ .NET3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UCMA 2.0 is only for Server Based Application and does not support to create client applications.